# How to access leaflet functionality with buttons that are not child components of a <MapContainer> with React Leaflet?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have a basic React app where a user can click on a `<Marker>` and the map will zoom to the selected marker, which works as expected:

```
   function MyMap() {

     <MapContainer className="map"
       center = {[40, 10]}
       zoom = {10}
       zoomControl = {false}
       >
       <Markers>

         const map = useMap();

         loc.map(loc => {
           return (
             <Marker
               key={loc.properties.id} 
               position={[loc.properties.y, loc.properties.x]}
               eventHandlers={{
                 click: () => {
                   map.setView([loc.properties.y, loc.properties.x], 16)
                 }
               }}>
             </Marker>
           )
         })
       </Markers>
     </MapContainer>
    }
```

Now what I want to do, is replicate the `map.setView()` functionality to work on a button click. This button is placed in a side panel next to the map and is not a child of the `<MapContainer>`. Each `<Marker>` has a corresponding button in a side panel.

The main App code looks something like this:

```
function App() {
  <SidePanel>
    <Button />
  </SidePanel>
  <MyMap />
}
```

Is there a way I could easily access the `map.setView()` function from the `<Marker>` eventHandler and use it on a `<Button>` in the side panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can access your location outside MapContainer, there is a prop on MapContainer called whenCreated which returns map.
You can use it outside of MapContainer.

```
const [map, setMap] = useState(null);
const loc = [];

<MapContainer whenCreated={setMap}>
  <Markers locations={loc} />
</MapContainer>
<SidePanel>
  {loc.map((loc, index) => {/* Render button and add use map saved in state to attach click handler */})}
</SidePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

As of the latest version of react-leaflet (4.0+ I believe), we can use `ref` instead of `whenCreated`, i.e.:

```js
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [map, setMap] = useState(null)

  return (
    <MapContainer
      ref={setMap}
    />
    ...
    </MapContainer>
  )
}
```

And we can use the `map` and all related functionality elsewere.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to access the event handler, you might just want to create a function in the button component, and pass that function down to the place where map variable is defined, and call the function in the child component, in its body, you can call the map() function.